# Trouble while installing packages for bioconductor in jupyter notebook with R 4.2.1 kernel

Tags: r, bioconductor

I'm trying to install packages for bioconductor in anaconda, and many of the packges give following error when I'm tyring to install.

For instance, when I run following command in the anaconda terminal:

**mamba install -c bioconda bioconductor-biocparallel
**

I get these error messages.

**Looking for: ['bioconductor-biocparallel']

bioconda/linux-64                                           Using cache
bioconda/noarch                                             Using cache
pkgs/r/noarch                                                 No change
pkgs/main/linux-64                                            No change
pkgs/main/noarch                                              No change
pkgs/r/linux-64                                               No change

Pinned packages:

- python 3.7.*

Encountered problems while solving:

- nothing provides r 3.2.2* needed by bioconductor-biocparallel-1.2.22-r3.2.2_0**

I tried googling but couldn't find any solution to this

Among the suggested solutions were using conda install instead or use 'sudo' command, but neither worked - couldn't install with conda install either and I cannot use 'sudo' command as I am using my university's server and I am not authorized to use that command.

Can someone help me with this?

According to some sources it may be because I have been using conda install, install packages and pip install altogether to install packages..?

Thank you!

I tried installing bioconda package using conda prompt.

Some of the packages install fine but some packages are keep running into problems and I cannot find a solution to it.

I described one of the error instance above...

Comment: This is interesting because over the past days I have also had issues getting bioconductor packages installed, in *any* version of conda, using this basic command `conda install -y -c bioconda bioconductor-deseq2`, every version of conda I have tried is left spinning on `Solving environment` and sometimes eventually resolves to report that a plethora of packages are not compatible. Never had this issue before. Maybe something happened in the `bionconda` channel?